# mysql select distinct(clientid) from table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem that I can't figure out.
 First I did this

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ClientID) AS ID 
FROM table 
WHERE column4 IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(column4) <> '' 
ORDER BY ClientID ASC
```

works great but my problem is now after I got the unique clientid`s from table.
Trying to take out the other unique clientid's that do not have value in column3 or 4

I did try this but is obviously wrong because I get in there the clientid that at 1 time had value in column3 and 4

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ClientID) AS ID 
FROM table 
WHERE ClientID != '(SELECT DISTINCT(ClientID) 
                      FROM table 
                      WHERE column4 IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(column4) <> '' )' 
ORDER BY ClientID ASC
```

the table is like this

```
Table
   ClientID - can be 2..3...4 times in the table
   ID       - unique id
   column3 - can be empty
   column4 - can be empty
   column5 - can be empty
```

Comment: Your question is not clear please elaborate it more

Comment: Not necessarily your issue, but I wouldn't `SELECT ClientID AS ID` when `ID` is already a column in your database.

Comment: i need to take out only the unique clientid that never had a value in column3 and 4

Comment: Your question is not clear elaborate more and place your table and some example data on http://sqlfiddle.com/.. but it looks like you have an normalisation problem here column3, column4 and column5 looks like meta data here..

Comment: explain in a detailed form what do you want to achieve or what's your problem

Answer (score 0):

`Select distinct (clientid) as id 
From table
Where length(column4) < > 0 and length(column3)< >0`

To check whether a colimn is null or empty , ude LENGTH() function.

Comment: Almost the same result. For example clientid 123 is 3 times in table and 1 time has value in column3 and 4. If it had value i dont want to take it out.. only the clientid that never had value in column3 and 4

Comment: Then check for column3 also...use AND condition..see edited answer

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE ClientID != 'SELECT ...'` is incorrect. The quotes around the subquery turn it into a string, removing any "queryness" it has. You should be doing

WHERE ClientID != (SELECT ....)

instead. Or preferably `NOT IN`, instead of `!=`.

Comment: Yes you are right but now my problem is that the subquerry returns more then 1 row :)

Comment: Hence the `NOT IN` option. (in)equality tests expect single values. `NOT IN` works on a set basis.

Comment: OW MY... sir you made my day :) if i can i`ll give you a token of my appreciation.